# How to configure Datadog alert when things are stuck in the queue for more then 2 hours?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

I want to get notified when any errors or logs are stuck in queue for more then 2 hours. how can I setup Datadog alert for that.

I tried this way. I set "If this monitor stays in **Alert or No Data** Renotify in every ****2** **hours.
[image]